# Laravel Authorization doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authorization, laravel-blade

I'm trying to hide a button and show it only to the admin, I think i writed the code well but still can't get the result i want, i can't see the button with the admin account neither with a normal user account

The FolderPolicy code

```
public function create(User $user)
{
    if($user->is_admin)
        return true;
}
```

the view

```
        @can('create')
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('newdoss') }}">New Folder</a>
        @endcan
```

the AuthServiceProvider file

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    'App\Folder' => 'App\Policies\FolderPolicy',
];
```

i know there is other ways to get the result i want by checking direclty if the authenticated user is an admin, but i want to figure out why this one is not working.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any roles/permissions libraries such as [entrust](https://github.com/zizaco/entrust)? If you aren't you may want to look into it if it doesn't force you to restructure your applicatoin too much already. `@role('admin')
    <p>This is visible to users with the admin role. Gets translated to 
    \Entrust::role('admin')</p>
@endrole`

Comment: no, i have a column in database called is_admin, and im working with laravel policies.

Comment: @Mehdi did you register this policy in the service provider?

Comment: its a small application and i have just two roles, so i don't think i need a library for that, i'm just trying to understand laravel, and i know i can solve my probleme with an @if(Auth::user()->is_admin)<p>my text</p>@endif
but i want to learn more about policies in laravel.

Comment: @Devon Yes i did, take look i edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which resource, or model, you are trying to create.  With create, you can pass the name of the class.  For updates and deletes, you can pass the instance of the class.

```
@can('create', \App\Folder::class)
```

You also need to return false when the policy fails.  You can simplify your create method to:

```
public function create(User $user)
{
    return (bool) $user->is_admin
}
```

Comment: Yes i tried that when i checked the laravel documentation, but it doesn't work, and that's why i said i think my code is correct but cant figure out why it's not working

Comment: Oh thanks, it works now, when i added the backslash. I have another question please, do you think it's logical tu use the create method for a button ?

Comment: Seems fine, would keep the UX focused on what the user can do.